# How to reconcile the following error: "JVM cannot use large page memory because it does not have enough privilege to lock pages in memory"?

Tags: security, java

Please help!!!  I wonder how can I reconcile the following error: "JVM cannot use large page memory because it does not have enough privilege to lock pages in memory"?

The settings are:
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms20g -Xmx20g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseLargePages -Duser.timezone="GMT" %DEBUG%

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a page on Sun's website about this: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/largememory.jsp

Here's the relevant information for what is likely your problem:

> Only Windows Server 2003 supports
>   large page memory. In order to use it,
>   the administrator must first assign
>   additional privilege to the user who
>   will be running the application:
>
> 1. select Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security
>      Policy
> 2. select Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment
> 3. double click "Lock pages in memory", add users and/or groups
> 4. reboot the machine
>
> Note the above steps are needed even
>   if it's the administrator who will be
>   running the application, as
>   administrators by default do not have
>   the privilege to lock pages in memory.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-the-lock-pages-in-memory-option-windows?view=sql-server-ver15 - Applies to Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 (uses gpedit.msc)